# How to compute this arithmatic series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was wondering if the way I have computed this arithmatic series is correct, I wasn't sure of my answer since it was using logs and I also had to calculate 100! through google since my calculator couldn't handle it.

[image]

for the numerator I deduced that it was a arithmatic series and did the following:

n =100

i = 1

log(base 2)  ((101*100)/2)

= log(base 2)  (5050)
= 12.3

for the denominator I was a little unsure since i wasn't able to calculate 100! in my calculator.

log(base 8)  (1*2*3*...*100)

= log(base 8)  (100!)

= (log 100!)/(log8)

= 174.92

then putting it altogether i got:

12.3/174.92

= 0.07

so is my answer correct or am i way off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that $\log_b(x) + \log_b(y) = \log_b(xy)$ so that your numerator becomes $\sum_{i = 1}^{100} \log_2(i) = \log_2(\prod_{i = 1}^{100} i) = \log_2(100!)$.

Now use the base change rule from base $b$ to base $c$: $\log_b(x) = \frac{\log_c(x)}{\log_c(b)}$.

This gives us $\log_2(100!) = \frac{\log_8(100!)}{\log_8(2)}$ and thus the answer to your question is $\frac{1}{\log_8(2)} = 3$.

Comment: The answer is $3$, not $\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: My bad, I answered too quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, does the symbol '∏' just mean 1*2*3*4.. instead of 1+2+3+4.. ?

Comment: Also, how does the log8 (100!) cancel to be 1 in the last step?

Comment: Yes, see [capital Pi notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Capital_Pi_notation). We have $\frac{\log_2(100!)}{\log_8(100!)} = \frac{ \frac{\log_8(100!)}{\log_2(8)}}{\log_8(100!)} = \frac{1}{\log_2(8)}$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT #$1$:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{100}\log_2{i}=\log_2\prod\limits_{i=1}^{100}i$$

HINT #$2$:

$$\frac{log_2{N}}{log_8{N}}=log_2{8}$$